# How does Gk. "hieros" differ from its cognate Gk. "oistros" with an "h"?

Tags: etymology, sound-change

***[oestrus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oestrus#Etymology)***

> From the Latin **oestrus** ("gadfly”, “sting”, “frenzy"), from the Ancient Greek **οἶστρος** (oistros).

***[hiero-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hiero-#Etymology)***

> From Ancient Greek prefix **ἱερo-** (**hiero-**), from **ἱερός** (**hieros**, "sacred, holy")

**[ἱερός](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%B1%CE%B5%CF%81%CF%8C%CF%82#Ancient_Greek)**

> From Proto-Indo-European ***ish₂ros**. There are a number of candidate cognates with this word. 
>   Compare Sanskrit इषिर (iṣirá) and Oscan  (aisusis).

Both the two words derive from the same PIE noun *ish₂ros, but why did the Ancient Greek decendants own different meanings with a prefixed "h" from each other, further giving "hiero-" and "oestrus"?

Comment: I quite doubt it's from PIE ish₂ros, I suspect it should be ish₁ros. Wikidictionary is a very unreliable source.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to give a partial answer.

According to Chantraine (Dictionnaire Étymologique Grec), Ancient Greek *oistros* and *hieros* **might** be related but this is not sure.

And Ancient Greek *hieros* does not have a clear well-defined meaning but several ones, so some linguists believe that two formerly separate words have been merged into one word (*hieros*).

Returning to your question: "... why did the Ancient Greek decendants own different meanings ..." — Maybe their meanings are so different from each other because they are not related. Sure, there are drastic semantic changes but if meanings are too different, a theory of relationship becomes too weak.

Answer (score 2):

Mine is also a partial answer. I'm not commenting on the etymology of the Greek words in your question.

In Attic Greek ἱερός, there's a diacritic over iota (in some other dialects there was psilosis, or h-dropping). It's called "rough breathing" (Lat. spiritus asper; Greek δασὺ πνεῦμα). Usually, Anlaut (word-initial) spiritus asper in Greek corresponds to PIE *s.

In the case of Greek ἱερός, it's a different story. Sihler 1995 argues that

> "Initial /h/ sometimes results from the anticipation of an intervocalic /h/ from -s-. (§174.2)"

There's also another rule here: an intervocalic *s was lost in Greek (*s>*h>0) (Sihler 1995, §172).